# problem with connecting to server

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, networking, db4o

I have a problem connecting to a port in asp.net web application.

This is the code that i'm using:

```
internal static IObjectContainer Client

    {
        get
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current; 

            IObjectContainer objectClient = context.Items[KEY_DB4O_CLIENT] as IObjectContainer; 

            if (objectClient == null)

            {
                objectClient = Db4oClientServer.OpenClient("localhost", 8372, "duran", "");                    

                context.Items[KEY_DB4O_CLIENT] = objectClient;

            } 

            return objectClient;
        }

    } 

    private static IObjectServer Server

    {
        get
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current; 

            if (objectServer == null)

            {
                string yapFilePath = context.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[KEY_DB4O_FILE_NAME]); 

                objectServer = Db4oClientServer.OpenServer(yapFilePath, 8372);

                objectServer.GrantAccess("duran", "");             

            } 

            return objectServer;
        }

    }
```

the error i'm getting is :

*Server Error in '/' Application.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8372*

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

*Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8372*

*Source Error:*

```
Line 36:          {
Line 37: 
Line 38:                objectClient = Db4oClientServer.OpenClient("localhost", 8372, "duran", ""); Line 39:                     
Line 40:                context.Items[KEY_DB4O_CLIENT] = objectClient;
```

I dont understand how to solve this problem. I'm stuck with this from the past 36 hours.

Please help me

Thanks in anticiption

Comment: check this link it might help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/5ab1d80b-a7b8-4bb6-a608-b5578aea009a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not certain, but this error is
>   typically a result of the port not
>   being open on the server. This can be
>   due to firewall settings or antivirus
>   solutions blocking traffic.

this sentence is from from [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-dynamics-crm/406539-no-connection-could-made-because-target-machine-actively.html)